# How to use onitemClickListener with Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement onItemClickListener in Fragment class but unfortunately it is not working properly... here is the source code.. please let me know what is the error??

NetworkDetailsFragment.java(My Fragment class)

public class NetworkDetailsFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

```
        private ListView listView;
        private View networkDetailsView;
        private QOSNetworkDetailsAdapter qosNetworkDetailsAdapter;
        private QOSNetworkDetailsDatabaseHelper qosNetworkDetailsDatabaseHelper;
        private SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;


        private String LOG_TAG = NetworkDetailsFragment.class.getSimpleName();




        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Inside onCreateView() method");

            networkDetailsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.network_details, container, false);
            listView = (ListView) networkDetailsView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            qosNetworkDetailsDatabaseHelper = new QOSNetworkDetailsDatabaseHelper(getActivity());

            Cursor cursor = qosNetworkDetailsDatabaseHelper.getRecord();

            String[] columns = {QOSNetworkDetailsDatabaseConstants.COLUMN_NETWORK_TYPE,
                                QOSNetworkDetailsDatabaseConstants.COLUMN_NETWORK_STATUS,
                                QOSNetworkDetailsDatabaseConstants.COLUMN_LATITUDE,
                                QOSNetworkDetailsDatabaseConstants.COLUMN_LONGITUDE,
                                QOSNetworkDetailsDatabaseConstants.COLUMN_TIME};

            int[]  to = new int[]{
                    R.id.networkType,
                    R.id.networkStatus,
                    R.id.latitudeAndLongitude,
                    R.id.date
            };

            /*SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this, R.layout.activity_network_info,
                    cursor,
                    columns,
                    to,
                    0);*/

            simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.activity_network_info, cursor, columns, to, 0);

            qosNetworkDetailsAdapter = new QOSNetworkDetailsAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), qosNetworkDetailsDatabaseHelper.getRecord(), false);
            listView.setAdapter(qosNetworkDetailsAdapter);


            return networkDetailsView;
        }


        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
             listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }



        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            String countryCode =
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("code"));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    countryCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }


    }
```

network_details.xml(i.e list_view.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/network_details_fragment_string"
     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

       />

</LinearLayout>




 activity_network_info.xml(list items)



<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/black" 
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/networkStatus"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@drawable/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/networkType"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@drawable/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/latitudeAndLongitude"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@drawable/lightblue"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@drawable/lightblue"
                android:textSize="15sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

List is getting populated to the screen... but onItemClickListener is not working in this code... please let me know what is the error.. Thanks

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: No, i am not getting any  Errors

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend FragmentActivity instead of Fragment...

Answer (score 0):

If you use a ListFragment, your ListView Id in layout must be android.R.id.list

like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@android:id/list" />
```

Comment: i say that because you have the onItemClick method (witch is override) so, i think you use a ListFragment. 
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this); in onActivityCreated is useless in this case